SwiftUI .onAppear not called on iPad in a NavigationStack when selecting a new item to show
I'm building an app that shows a list of locations to choose from, and then pushes a detail view of that location with a Map showing the location.  When I use this code on a iPhone everything works as expected, however, when I use it on an iPad the onAppear method that I use to set the maps region and pin never gets called for subsequent locations.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the detail being always on screen.
var body: some View {
        List(locations, id: \.id) { location in
            NavigationLink(value: location) {
                LocationRowView(location: location)
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Location.self) { location in
            LocationView(location: location)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }

And the LocationView
struct LocationView: View {
    var location: Location
    
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic

    private var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.address.latitude, longitude: location.address.longitude)
    }
    
    private var locationRegion: MKCoordinateRegion {
        MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationCoordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    }
    
    private var locationPosition: MapCameraPosition {
        MapCameraPosition.region(locationRegion)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(position: $position) {
                Marker("", coordinate: locationCoordinate)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear {
            position = locationPosition
        }
    }
}

To be clear when I run this code on the iPad I get a sidebar with my list of locations and a blank detail screen behind it, as expected.  When I select a location I get my detail screen showing the map with the pin of the location chosen.  Now the bug is when I select a different location the pin moves, but the map stays centered on the first location when I was expecting the map to also move and have the new pin centered.
The code I've written is supposed to center the map on the passed in locations coordinates which it does the first time by entering the .onAppear modifier, but that doesn't happen on subsequent location selections.
If I remove my .onAppear call and just leave the position as .automatic then subsequent selections do move the map and show the new pin, unless I've interacted with the map in any way (zoom, pan, etc.)

onAppear is just for actions, for states its best to get your source of truth correct. I.e. move the state up and set it when they select the row, then pass in the binding to that for the Map to use.

Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests, the .onAppear{..} gets called every time and the Map centers on the selected location.
On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4, tested on real iOS 17 devices (iPad and iPhone) and macCatalyst.
Maybe you have some other code that is triggering your problem. Can show my test code if required.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Interesting. By making some basic assumptions about how they have set up NavigationSplitView, I can reproduce on iOS 17.4 simulator, Xcode 15.3.

I was using a simple NavigationStack

Rob, are you using a NavigationStack like your title suggests or are you using a NavigationSplitView? You said "when I run this code on the iPad I get a sidebar with my list of locations and a blank detail screen behind it, as expected", which sounds extremely like a NavigationSplitView.

You can change onAppear to onChange. Pass initial: true so that it is triggered the first time the view appears too.
.onChange(of: locationPosition, initial: true) { _, newValue in
    position = newValue
}

That said, using navigationDestination this way to navigate to a detail view (though it works) is not documented. I would recommend using the selection of the List to drive the NavigationSplitView.
Here is an example:
struct Location: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let address: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let name: String
    
    // Hashable implementation omitted
}

let locations = [
    Location(address: .init(latitude: 40.776863, longitude: -73.874069), name: "Foo"),
    Location(address: .init(latitude: 25.795160, longitude: -80.279594), name: "Bar"),
]

struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @State var selection: Location?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            LocationList(selection: $selection)
        } detail: {
            if let selection {
                LocationView(location: selection)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LocationList: View {
    @Binding var selection: Location?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(locations, selection: $selection) { location in
            NavigationLink(value: location) {
                Text(location.name)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}

struct LocationView: View {
    var location: Location
    
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic

    private var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.address.latitude, longitude: location.address.longitude)
    }
    
    private var locationRegion: MKCoordinateRegion {
        MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationCoordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    }
    
    private var locationPosition: MapCameraPosition {
        MapCameraPosition.region(locationRegion)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Map(position: $position) {
                Marker("", coordinate: locationCoordinate)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onChange(of: locationPosition, initial: true) { _, newValue in
            position = newValue
        }
    }
}

